# how to put a title in the actionbar to know which page it is?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

How to put a title in the action bar to show the user what page is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to change the `ActionBar` title when you swipe to a page using `ViewPager`. In that case, here's a quick example:

```
    final OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            getActionBar().setTitle("Page " + position);
        }
    };
    mYourViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);
```

Comment: @user3386634 Is this the answer you were looking for? If so, will you mark it as accepted, please?

Comment: I'm sorry ! how can I do it I'm new her.